# Extract data for all days for last 30 days from R data frame

Tags: r, date, datetime-format

I am totally new to R environment and I'm stuck at Date operations. The scenario is, I have a daily database of customer activity of a certain Store, and I need to extract last 30 months data starting from current date. 
In other words, suppose today is 18-NOV-2014, I need all the data from 18-OCT-2014 till today in a separate data-frame. To extract it, what kind of iteration logic should I write in R?

Comment: Please supply [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including (a sample of) your data and any code you've already tried.

Comment: And your desired output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need an iteration. What you could do is, assuming your data.frame is called X, and the date column, DATE, you could write:

```
X$DATE=as.Date(X$DATE, format='%d-%B-%Y')
```

the 'format' argument is to match your date format you specify in you question. Then, to get the lines you are  interested in, something like:

```
X[X$DATE>=as.Date(today(),format='%d-%B-%Y')-30)]
```

which is all the lines that are after today - 30 days.
Does this help at all?

Comment: Yes @Nikos, that is the exact thing I needed!

Comment: @DavidArenburg it is an equivalent of Sys.Date()

Comment: I don't have that function in R, do you?

Comment: Apologies. David is right, sorry I had already loaded lubridate in my project. Sys.Date() is perhaps better (to use only base R). Thank you for mentioning it David.

Comment: Yes, apologies from my side too. Thanks David.